# keep mouse hover effect while pointer is on any element of a svg icon

Tags: css, svg, hover

I have a two-colors svg icon and want to change its color when mouse is hover.

```css
.icotop{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}

.icotop > .fil0{
    fill:#ccc;
}

.icotop > .fil1{
    fill:white;
}

.icotop:hover{
    fill:red;  // doesn't work
}

.icotop .fil0:hover{
    fill:red;  // this works
}
```

```html
<svg class='icotop' viewBox="0 0 1.99 1.99">
    <path class="fil0" d="M1.8 1.99l-1.62 0 -0.05 -0.03c-0.06,-0.02 -0.1,-0.07 -0.12,-0.13 -0.02,-0.06 -0.01,-0.23 -0.01,-0.31l0 -0.9c0,-0.15 0,-0.15 0.08,-0.25 0.06,-0.07 0.24,-0.25 0.32,-0.31 0.06,-0.05 0.07,-0.04 0.1,-0.06l1.3 0c0,0 0,0 0.01,0 0.01,0.01 0.02,0.01 0.05,0.02 0.04,0.02 0.08,0.06 0.11,0.11 0.03,0.07 0.02,0.19 0.02,0.27l0 1.18c0,0.15 0.02,0.27 -0.09,0.36 -0.05,0.04 -0.07,0.03 -0.1,0.05z"/>
    <path class="fil1" d="M1.52 1.07c0.03,0.01 0.05,0.03 0.05,0.06l0 0.48c-0.01,0.02 -0.03,0.04 -0.07,0.04 -0.26,0 -0.53,0 -0.8,0 -0.03,0 -0.21,0 -0.23,0 -0.03,-0.01 -0.05,-0.03 -0.05,-0.06 0,-0.04 0,-0.46 0,-0.48 0.01,-0.03 0.03,-0.04 0.07,-0.04 0.06,0 1.01,0 1.03,0z"/>
    <path class="fil1" d="M1.52 0.28c0.06,0.02 0.05,0.07 0.05,0.12 0,0.05 0,0.29 0,0.31 -0.01,0.06 -0.08,0.05 -0.13,0.05 -0.04,0 -0.67,0 -0.7,0 -0.05,-0.02 -0.04,-0.07 -0.04,-0.12 0,-0.04 -0.01,-0.29 0,-0.31 0.01,-0.06 0.07,-0.05 0.12,-0.05 0.05,0 0.68,0 0.7,0z"/>
</svg>
```

Problem is because color of `fil0` changes back when mouse is over `fil1`.

So how to change the color of `fil0` when mouse is over any element of `icotop`

Comment: Do `.fil1{pointer-events:none;}` Read more about [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.icotop{
 cursor:pointer;
 position:relative;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
}

.icotop > .fil0{
 fill:#ccc;
}

.icotop > .fil1{
 fill:white;
}
/* This */
.icotop:hover .fil0{
 fill:red; 
}
/* instead of these */
.icotop:hover{
fill:red;  
}

.icotop .fil0:hover{
fill:red; 
}
/* end instead of these */
```

```html
<svg class='icotop' viewBox="0 0 1.99 1.99">
  <path class="fil0" d="M1.8 1.99l-1.62 0 -0.05 -0.03c-0.06,-0.02 -0.1,-0.07 -0.12,-0.13 -0.02,-0.06 -0.01,-0.23 -0.01,-0.31l0 -0.9c0,-0.15 0,-0.15 0.08,-0.25 0.06,-0.07 0.24,-0.25 0.32,-0.31 0.06,-0.05 0.07,-0.04 0.1,-0.06l1.3 0c0,0 0,0 0.01,0 0.01,0.01 0.02,0.01 0.05,0.02 0.04,0.02 0.08,0.06 0.11,0.11 0.03,0.07 0.02,0.19 0.02,0.27l0 1.18c0,0.15 0.02,0.27 -0.09,0.36 -0.05,0.04 -0.07,0.03 -0.1,0.05z"/>
  <path class="fil1" d="M1.52 1.07c0.03,0.01 0.05,0.03 0.05,0.06l0 0.48c-0.01,0.02 -0.03,0.04 -0.07,0.04 -0.26,0 -0.53,0 -0.8,0 -0.03,0 -0.21,0 -0.23,0 -0.03,-0.01 -0.05,-0.03 -0.05,-0.06 0,-0.04 0,-0.46 0,-0.48 0.01,-0.03 0.03,-0.04 0.07,-0.04 0.06,0 1.01,0 1.03,0z"/>
  <path class="fil1" d="M1.52 0.28c0.06,0.02 0.05,0.07 0.05,0.12 0,0.05 0,0.29 0,0.31 -0.01,0.06 -0.08,0.05 -0.13,0.05 -0.04,0 -0.67,0 -0.7,0 -0.05,-0.02 -0.04,-0.07 -0.04,-0.12 0,-0.04 -0.01,-0.29 0,-0.31 0.01,-0.06 0.07,-0.05 0.12,-0.05 0.05,0 0.68,0 0.7,0z"/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: don't use `//` for comments in CSS, it may break your code, use `/* */`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change CSS rule

`.icotop:hover .fil0{
    fill:red;  // this works
}`